# Is there an example of a Lipschitz function of a Gaussian vector for which $f(Z)-\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ is not sub-Gaussian

Tags: expected-value, bounds, subgaussianity

**Definitions**:

A random variable $X$ is called sub-Gaussian with parameter $\sigma^2$ if there exists $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \quad \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]\le e^{\frac{\sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2}}$$

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is called $L$-Lipschitz if $|f(X)-f(Y)|\le L \|x-y\|$.

Note:Usually, We take the $L_2$-norm for the RHS.

---

**Theorem**:

If $Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_n$ are standard normal variables ($Z_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$), and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $L$-Lipschitz function, then $f(Z)-\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ is sub-Gaussian. (Taken from [Concentration of Measure 3 by Jarosław Błasiok](http://statisticalml.stat.columbia.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/jarek-lecture3.pdf), Page 21)

---

**Question**:

Assume that we apply the same $L$-Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ on $Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_n$ such that $Z=(Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_n)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, meaning that the random variables are normal (but not standard) and we may have $\mathbb{E}[Z_i Z_j] \neq 0$ for some $i,j$.

Can we define $f$ such that $f(Z)-\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ is no more sub-Gaussian?

To clarify: We can define $f$ and $\Sigma$ (the covariance matrix of the Gaussian random vector) as we would like to. The question says: "Can we select $f$ and $\Sigma$ such that $f(Z)-\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ is not sub-Gaussian?"

---

**My work**:

I've found out that the theorem may not hold if $f$ is Lipschitz but not convex (in this [link](https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf), page 212). However, I believe in my case, reaching a counterexample should be much easier. I couldn't find any theorem which states that if the variables $Z_i$ have correlation, then $f(Z)-\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ is sub-Gaussian. So, I thought maybe if we define $Z_i$'s somehow that they are correlated, then the counterexample could be made. The difficulty for me is that for each Lipschitz function that I define, I should prove that

$$
\forall \sigma\in\mathbb{R} \quad \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \quad \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda (f(Z)-\mathbb{E}(f(Z))}] \gt e^{\frac{\sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2}}
$$

And proving this is where I can't proceed further. I'm not sure but maybe my approach is wrong.

Note: There is a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622523/lipschitz-function-of-independent-sub-gaussian-random-variables), and also another one [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334860/talagrands-inequality-for-the-discrete-cube).

Answer (score 0):

If $Z_i\sim N(,\Sigma)$ then $Z_i=\Sigma^{1/2}Y_i$ are $N(0,1)$, where $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is any square root of $\Sigma$.  So $f(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)=(f\circ g)(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$, where $g$ is multiplication by $\Sigma^{1/2}$.

Clearly $f\circ g$ is still Lipschitz. If $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$, the Lipschitz constant is bounded above by $L\sqrt{\lambda}$.

So, no. But you do need to take the extra factor of $\sqrt{\lambda}$ into account, especially if you're going to look at a collection of $f$s and $Z$s that might have different $\Sigma$s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I still have difficulties understanding what you wrote. Would you please clarify: 1) What do you mean by "any square root of $\Sigma$"? (since $\Sigma$ is a matrix) 2) What does your last sentence mean? ("you do need to take ..."), does it mean that there is a $\lambda$ for which we can show that $f(Z)-\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ is not sub-Gaussian? 3) I believe you meant $Y_i = \Sigma^{1/2} Z_i$ when you wrote $Z_i=\Sigma^{1/2} Y_i$. Is that true?